# File path for upload as PHP URL parameter

Tags: php

I am trying to pass a path to a local file to a PHP upload form.  I have a basic upload form with an `<input type=file etc..>` and I am trying to set this value using the parameter I passed in when calling the PHP script from my browser.

In searching around a good bit, I understand this is not possible for security reasons.  Otherwise someone could automatically upload your files when you went to their site.  Is it true that specifying the value for the `<input type=file >` is not possible?  If so, are there any alternate ways of doing this or any workarounds?

Thanks

Comment: The only possibility I can imagine is to create a browser extension and then force users to install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/). It has a lot of good features like:

- Restricting the type of files the user can select in the dialog
- Multi-file uploading
- Ajax-like file uploads

I am not, however, sure if it allows you to set the default directory. An initial look at the configuration options and the reference manual for the `Flash.net.File` class makes me think that it is not possible even with Flash. However, the file-type restriction might make life a little easier on your users.

Java Webstart may be worth looking into as well. However, you have to worry about application signing, warning messages, and other things.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that this is not possible.  The way that `<input>` is handled is entirely up to the browser, and you have no control over it.

You could look into building a Flash uploader, but I doubt it's file browse capability is any different.

Comment: Ok, could I somehow require a little more intervention by the user to make it work?  When the user clicks browse in the <input type=file> is there anyway I could make the default location it opens up in File Upload something of my choosing?  In that folder I would have only the file I want them to upload so there would be less confusion then they would select OK.  I will only be using Firefox as a browser.

Comment: Not without installing software client-side.

Answer (score -1):

instead of using `<input type="file">`, you can use CURL library to upload the file via POST. And this way you can pass the file path as parameter to your script. I haven't tried it myself though.